# Copying files from one directory into another

Tags: bash, dd

Exactly what I'm trying to achieve is more complex than the title suggests, but I wanted to keep it reasonably short. I am attempting to do the following; (I'm still very new to bash)

"Take a directory of images whose name is given as an argument, such as the directory XXX, and that produces another directory, whose name is given as another argument, that contains copies of those images, but that are half the size (in linear dimensions)."

I have attempted to do that with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then    
    orgdir$1
fi
if [ "$2" != "" ]; then    
    cpydir=$2    
fi    
find "${orgdir}" | while read -r file   
do    
    filesize=$(wc -c <"$orgdir$file")
    dd if=$orgdir of=$cpydir bs=$(($filesize/2))
done
```

Running that in the terminal as ./script.sh ./Test ./TestMove I get the following errors.

```
line 11 ./Test./Test: No such file or directory.
```

I've tried just getting the wc -c of $file but that says wc takes directory as standard input

and;

```
line 12 ""/2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is """/2")
```

Presumably because filesize is not being given the correct value?

I'm also not sure using dd to copy the files and half the size is the best way, but am not able to find any others.

Comment: Copying half the bytes of an image file is probably not going to result in a valid image.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that when I first read the task. I'm not sure if I'm meant to copy half of it or compress it to be honest. Is the latter possible?

Comment: If he literally means "turn a 300x300 image into a 150x150 image", then you need to use a program that understands the format of the file.

Comment: The task was to write a script does the task I mentioned in the op, so I guess not, it's only meant to be a very basic course.

Comment: You are missing the `equal` sign in the first assignment. `orgdir=$1`. Note that you should exit the script if the parameters *are* empty, because you are leaving the variable(s) undefined otherwise.

Comment: Another thing is that you do not need to use '$origdir' in the wc command, as $file already contains the path. And if you insist on using dd, you would need to specify a file as argument 'of', not only a directory. (But as others have noted, using dd there makes no sense, ImageMagick seems to be appropriate.)

Comment: @MarkSetchell my bad, I forgot about that, yes your answer worked fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a single command from the **ImageMagick** suite which is installed on most Linux distros:

```
cd "$1" && mogrify -path "$2" -resize 50% *.jpg
```